# Gatling scenario appears to have network or HTTP corruption at high concurrent load on Windows

Tags: windows, scala, akka, netty, gatling

I have a very simple [Gatling](https://github.com/gatling/gatling) scenario which hits a single HTTP endpoint with concurrent users.

When I run this for 30 seconds with 10 requests per second, everything is fine.

When I run this for 30 seconds at 60 requests per second on Windows, I get very strange errors that look to me like the underlying network connections are getting corrupted or are being misused. Perhaps there is a race condition or concurrency bug somewhere in Gatling or somewhere else in my system.

I don't get the same problems on a linux machine.

The web server is `nginx` and `PHP`. I don't suspect that is the cause of the problem, but I might be wrong.

How can I track down and fix this bug?

### The scenario code

```
val scn = scenario("my scenario - one endpoint only")
    .exec(http("fetch")
        .get("http://my.website/page"))
    .inject(
        constantUsersPerSec(requestsPerSecond)
            .during(30.seconds)
            .randomized)
    .protocols(httpProtocol)

setUp(scn)
```

### Symptoms

The scenario reports about 8% failure rate, with errors that look like the server is replying with malformed HTTP responses, returning HTML code where the HTTP status line should be. These vary in the details, but here is a representative example:

```
2017-02-20 17:30:59,875 DEBUG org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyRequestSender - invalid version format: <META
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: <META
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:130)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:84)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseDecoder.createMessage(HttpResponseDecoder.java:118)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder.decode(HttpObjectDecoder.java:219)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.decode(HttpClientCodec.java:152)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Similarly, the server logs include invalid requests where the client has sent HTML where the HTTP request line should be:

```
10.56.4.130 - - [20/Feb/2017:17:30:59 +0000] "span class=\x22id4-cta-size-small id5-cta id4-cta-color-blue id4-cta-small-blue\x22><a hr" 400 166 "-" "-" "-" 0.179 -

10.56.4.130 - - [20/Feb/2017:17:31:00 +0000] "<!doctype html>" 400 166 "-" "-" "-" 0.070 -
```

### Version info

I am using:

- **O/S**: Windows 8.1 64 bit

  - **Virus Scanner**: I have Kapersky which intercepts network traffic. I tried turning it off, which made no difference. I don't know if it was "really" off.
  - **VPN**: My machine has a Windows Direct Connect VPN. The target site does not fall within that VPN.
- **Java**: "1.8.0_121", Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
- **Scala**: 2.11.8
- **Gatling**: 2.2.3

  - **Akka**: 2.4.12
  - **io.netty.netty-handler**: 4.0.42.Final

    - (4.0.41.Final was requested by netty-reactive-streams v 1.0.8, I wonder if that's significant)